# Finding the points of intersection on a circle

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Before addressing my issues, below is the question from a past examination paper along with a diagram I dre in order to facilitate readers.

---

> 3(a) A circle has center $C(5, 8)$ and radius $\sqrt{29}$
>
> (ii) The circle cuts the y-axis at $R$ and $Q$, where $Q$ is above $R$. Find the coordinates of $Q$ and $R$, and find the equation of the tangent at $Q$.

---

### Diagram

[image: Diagram]

---

First thing I did (well, it was requested) was find the equation of this circle, which turned out to be $x^2-10x+y^2-16y+60=0$.

Now, not only from the graph shown above but also the one I drew on paper I am able to find out that the points for $Q$ and $R$ are $(0,10)$ and $(0,6)$ respectively. However, that is not what the examiner would like the student to do (granted I got the answer anyway and still think I shouldn't be penalized for it).

Given that I have no information apart form the fact that triangle $CQR$ is an isosceles triangle with two equal sides having the length $\sqrt29$.

With this information alone I'm not quite capable (yet) to proceed with the question. How would one proceed?

Comment: Equation of tangent at a point is $(x_1,y_1)$ is $xx_1+yy_1+g(x+x_1)+f(y+y_1)+c=0$

Comment: For points of intersection with $y-axis$ , set $x=0$ and solve for the quadratic in $y$. :)

Comment: @Mann - Thanks a million times again haha, overlooked such a simply solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 1.

Equation of circle: $x^2−10x+y^2−16y+60=0$

## Step 2.

For points Q and R substitute values of $x=0$, and $y=y$ into the circle equation.
That will give you $y^2-16y+60=0$

## Step 3.

Factorize this to get $(y-10)(y-6)=0$.
Therefore $y=6$ and $y=10$.

## Step 4.

So, we have the two point $(0,10)$ and $(0,6)$.

## Step 5.

Using the point $(5,8)$ and $(0,10)$ ,find the slope of the line. Using the equation $\dfrac{y1-y2}{x1-x2}$.
Therefore slope is $\frac{-2} {5}$.

## Step 6.

Since the tangent is perpendicular to the line $CQ$. The slope of the tangent is $\frac{5}{2}$.
$\text{Since slope 1*slope 2= -1}$.

## Step 7.

Therefore we can form the equation using the slope and the point $(0,10)$.

## Step 8.

The equation is $(y-10)=\frac{5}{2}(x-0)$. Which is $2y-20=5x$.

Comment: This does indeed make alot of sense. Wasn't aware that it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(0,8)$. Apply Pythagoras in $ACQ$ to find $AQ=2$. Furthermore the tangent line is perpendicular to $CQ$, hence its slope is $5/2$ and its intercept is $10$.